# How can can we show that a metric is asymptotically AdS?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, asymptotics

Given any metric, for example

$$
ds^2=d\tau^2+L^2\cosh(H\tau)d\vec{x}^2
$$
how can we show that this metric is asymptotically Euclidean AdS? Specicifally, when $\tau\rightarrow\pm\infty$ is it possible to show that this metric is assymptoticly AdS?

I would assume that we'd have to bring it in the form $ds^2=R^2(dz^2+d\vec{x}^2)$ where ofcourse my specific case has the time coordinate Wick rotated.

Comment: But that metric doen't seem Lorentzian. Do you mean asymptotically hyperbolic? Hyperbolic geometry is the Euclidean version of AdS geometry, i.e having maximal symmetries with negative constant Ricci curvature.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I will edit the question. I am talking here about Euclidean AdS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a formal answer because I am still confused by your last metric.

What is $R$ in your last metric? If it is a function, then, for example, $$ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{z^2}$$

is a hyperbolic metric. It is known as the [Poincare upper-half plane model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model).

But I think it's more convenient for me to write down some equations here instead of in the comment section.

Your first metric is already an exact hyperbolic metric, as you can find directly from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) in section 2.2.

Hyperbolic geometry can be realized in various models. The most well-known models are Poincare's upper half space model, and [Poincare's ball model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model). There're other models as well.

For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192432/the-metric-g-dx2-cosh2xdy2-is-complete) is the model you are talking about in your first metric. The metric $$g=dx^2+\cosh^2(x)dy^2$$

has negative constant Ricci scalar curvature $-1$. It is complete. This is known as the [Lobachevsky model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_systems_for_the_hyperbolic_plane), which was the original model that Nikolai Lobachevsky derived from the formulae of hyperbolic triangles.